# ViewPager inside Fragment doest show content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

im developing an android app which has a bottomnavigation that opens 3 different fragments without a viewpager. One fragment has a viewpager inside it which opens 2 fragments. these 2 fragments are the same fragment and each has a recyclerview inside it. my problem is that when I run the app everything except the viewpager runs as intended. I tried putting the fragment inside the viewpager instead of it and the fragment works. I even tried putting the viewpager in a empty activity which worked as well.

**This is my MainActivity which holds the BottomNavigation and its functionality:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    private BottomNavigationView navView;

    private Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    private Fragment fragment2 = new SearchFragment();
    private Fragment fragment3 = new SettingsFragment();
    private FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private Fragment active = fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "settings").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "search").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment1, "home").commit();

        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).addToBackStack("home").commit();
                active = fragment1;
                toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_search:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).addToBackStack("search").commit();
                active = fragment2;
                toolbar.setTitle("Search");
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active)
                    .show(fragment3).addToBackStack("settings").commit();
                active = fragment3;
                toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(Fragment fragment, int position) {
        if(fm.findFragmentByTag("playlist"+position) != null){
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).hide(active).add(R.id.main_container, fragment, "playlist"+position).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            active = fragment;
        } else {
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).add(R.id.main_container, fragment, "playlist"+position).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            active = fragment;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the MainActivityLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
    layout="@layout/action_bar"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_container_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/main_container"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        android:elevation="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my Fragment that implements the ViewPager:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        PlaylistsPagerAdapter playlistsPagerAdapter = new PlaylistsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        playlistsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PlaylistsFragment(),"private");
        playlistsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PlaylistsFragment(),"public");
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_home);
        viewPager.setAdapter(playlistsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_home);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    public class PlaylistsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> mFragmentListTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addFragment(Fragment playlistsFragment, String title) {
            mFragmentListTitle.add(title);
            mFragmentList.add(playlistsFragment);
        }

        public PlaylistsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return mFragmentList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentListTitle.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the HomeFragmentLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

**This is the PlaylistsFragment:**

```
public class PlaylistsFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "PlaylistsFragment";

    private ArrayList<String> mPlaylistName = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playlists, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        initNameBitmap(view);
    }

    private void initNameBitmap(View view){
        mPlaylistName.add("Playlist1");
        mPlaylistName.add("Playlist2");
        mPlaylistName.add("Playlist3");
        mPlaylistName.add("Playlist4");

        initRecyclerView(view);
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(View view){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_playlists);
        RecyclerViewAdapterPlaylists recyclerViewAdapterPlaylists = new RecyclerViewAdapterPlaylists(mPlaylistName, view.getContext(),this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterPlaylists);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getView().getContext()));
    }
}
```

**This is the PlaylistsFragments Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_playlists"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The weird thing is that it worked already. I tried around with onBackPressed and when i implemented this and pressed another View on the BottomNavigation than the back button on the phone and than the Home button it showed as intened:

```
fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragmentsHistory.get(fragmentsHistory.size()-1));
active = fragmentsHistory.get(fragmentsHistory.size()-1)
fragmentsHistory.remove(fragmentsHistory.size()-1);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you please upload the xml files?

Comment: ok i added the xml files

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.plans.PlansFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="#DBD8D8" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

your HomeFragmentLayout should be similar to this